# How do I upload photos from my camera?

Tags: 14.04, camera

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, I'm incredibly new at using it, and I'm trying to upload photos from a Nikon camera.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer one of these two questions:

Screenshots can be fullscreen (press the <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> button, or the active window (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScr</kbd>)

Usually for camera pictures, I pull the memory card and place it into a card reader which looks like a disk drive to my computer.

Comment: Found the screenshot thing, thanks. I do not own a card reader, unfortunately. Before switching to Ubuntu, I was able to do this fine so I'm a little confused.

Comment: New systems...  You connect your camera with a USB cable?  Just give it a shot.  Most likely it will open a window asking if you want to use a photo management program such as Shotwell to look at the files, or a file manager.

Comment: Already tried the USB. Nothing came up, and using Shotwell I can't find my camera either. I'm hopelessly lost.

Comment: There is an application on the Ubuntu Software Center that might help you - it is call GThumb Image Viewer (open the software center and type gthumb) - it apparently is able to read images from a wide variety of cameras.

Comment: GThumb also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Although the USB did not work, the SD card did, and GThumb worked fine in uploading.